# ARMv8: XZR use in LDUR/STUR instructions assembler error

Tags: arm

It is supposed XZR can be used in any register field of ARMv8 ISA, but when I try use in indexed addressing for load/store intruction, I always obtain errors:

```
ex2.s:3: Error: integer 64-bit register expected at operand 2 -- `ldr X1,[XZR,#0]'
ex2.s:4: Error: integer 64-bit register expected at operand 2 -- `ldur X2,[XZR,#1]'
ex2.s:8: Error: integer 64-bit register expected at operand 2 -- `stur X1,[XZR,#2]'
ex2.s:9: Error: integer 64-bit register expected at operand 2 -- `stur X3,[XZR,#0]'
ex2.s:14: Error: integer 64-bit register expected at operand 2 -- `stur X4,[XZR,#2]'
```

It is easy to bypass it, for example with the previous: 
    MOV X0, XZR
and then use X0, but I would like the reason.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because the ISA says so. `ld[u]r` uses the stack pointer rather than the zero register, because loading relative to the stack pointer is a frequently used and important operation, while loading relative to zero is not (particularly on modern large address spaces and with ASLR).

Comment: Thanks  EOF, I dont know about this particularity/limitation of this ISA. Certainly it takes more sense  with SP, but I am using aarch64 assembler for tests in the LegV8 ISA subset and pseudo-direct addressing in a little memory, and I still dont know about ASLR, sorry.